# Convert hexa to int

Tags: c#, hex, decimal, checksum

I'm trying to convert a byte to hex and calculate the checksum.
This is my array of byte with hex values.

```
byte[] tocrc = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 2, 2, 0, 1, 29, 07, 10, 20, 46, 46, 0 };
```

i need to calculate the checksum of this array.

```
 public static byte calcolacrc(byte[] tocrc)
    {
        byte crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            crc += data[i];
        }
        crc &= 0xff;
        return crc;
    }
```

My problem is that when i sum the byte with the hex number: **29**
It's sum the value 29 that is a int and not the hex **29** that is incorrect .
the correct value to sum is **41** in decimal

to convert decimal to hex i use this function:

```
value.ToString("X")
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your byte array contains four hex numbers (0xff) and the rest are decimal... If you want `29` and the others to be hex, add the `0x` in front of them.

Comment: Very thanks but now the question is,if i have AN hexadecimal number and i want to add this number to an array how can i do that.an hexadecimal is a string so can i insert this in a byte array thanks Andrea

Comment: A hexadecimal number is just a number. Hexadecimal is just a way to represent a value. `0x29 == 41 == 00101001`. If you do mean that you have an actual String like `"0x29"` that you're trying to parse into its corresponding integer value, I'm sure C# has some builtin method for that.

Comment: the problem is that i have this:
'byte[] datatocrc = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, statotab, bgetdata, bdata,}'
and bgetdata is a byte .to obtain this byte i do:
byte bgetdata = Convert.ToByte(datainteger.ToString("X"));
so this bgetdata will never have 0x as beginning

Comment: I'm not as familiar with C# as I would like to be so I may be missing something... It sounds to me like you have the numeric portion of the hexadecimal number, ie you want `0x29`, but have the String `"29"` or the actual integer `29`. If this is what you mean, then perhaps just concatenate `"0x"` and `datainteger.ToString("29")`?

Answer (score 3):

You did it right for the first 4, you just need to keep putting `0x` on the front of each number to make it be interpreted as hexadecimal.

```
byte[] tocrc = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x29, 0x07, 0x10, 0x20, 0x46, 0x46, 0x00 };
```

Answer (score 1):

In your array put `0x29` if you want HEX 29 value. And remember that your array is not from "hex" values - it is array of bytes, decimal or hex is only syntax of constant.